# Fast lagged dependent variables weighted least squares model on large datasets?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, autoregressive-models

I am looking to fit an autoregressive AR(p) model to 525600 observations, with weights. I want both the fitted values and the coefficients (including the intercept). I am able to do it, but I was wondering if there is a faster, better way.

Currently, I make the design matrix myself with `matfun()` from the time series `RW`. Reprex below:

```
order <- 10
ndat <- 525600
RW <- arima.sim(model= list(order = c(0, 1, 0)), n=ndat)[2:(ndat+1)]


matfun <- function(RW, order){
  RW <- as.matrix(RW)
  n <- nrow(RW)
  dmat <- matrix(1, n, order)
  for (j in 1:order) {
    dmat[, j] <- c(rep(0,j), RW[1:(n-j)])
  }
  return(dmat[(order+1):n,])
}

matt <- matfun(RW, order = order)
w <- runif(nrow(matt), 0, 1)


mod <- lm(RW[(order+1):ndat]~matt,weights=w)
```

With larger AR orders, both the design matrix and linear model step become slow. I tried the `ar()` function but it doesn't let me add weights, and I think the lack of grouping prevented `gls()` from `nlme` being helpful (and I couldn't figure out precalculated weights). I do know of the faster lm functions, but maybe there's an even better way? If there isn't a function that can do all this, do you see any way I could speed up any of the design matrix or `lm` step up?

TIA! :)

EDIT: It seems my question is poorly posed!! Thanks to
[Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) for commenting:

> You should be aware that including lagged variables in a regression is not the same as fitting an AR(p) model ...

I am definitely looking to include lagged variables as I have done above, not fit an AR(p) model as I stated.

Comment: I tried `library(nlme); RW0 <- RW[-(1:order)]; g1 <- gls(RW0 ~ 1, correlation = corARMA(p = 10), weights = ~1/w)` but it choked because it's trying to create one big correlation matrix (and not accounting for sparsity). You should be aware that including lagged variables in a regression is **not the same** as fitting an AR(p) model ...

Comment: Ahhhh thanks I see that now! I am definitely trying to include lagged variables - not fit an AR(p). Is there a way to not have AR(p) errors in gls()? Else I imagine my only option is speeding up matfun and the lm call.

Comment: The last three lines of your code take 0.4 seconds on my machine. How much faster do you need it to go? You could use `lm.wfit` or the `fastLm` package ... (The `matfun()` call takes about 0.06 seconds, so `lm()` is your main bottleneck ...)

Comment: Just as fast as I can get it - it is a step in every iteration of an algorithm. I've got `speedglm` going and that is what I'm now using (couldn't get WLS going in `fastLM`)- thanks! :)

Comment: If you've solved your problem you should probably post an answer (people can still post improved answers). It might help to add some benchmarking/profiling to your question and/or answer: e.g. if `speedglm` is fast enough that forming the design matrix is now a significant fraction of the time, that would be worth knowing. Also worth knowing the context (e.g., how fast is 'fast enough')

Comment: Will get on that!